# How to move Symfony 2 project to hosting?

Tags: php, symfony, host

I upload my project in My hosting service, this is the link to My web site.
please make a lock to now my problem `http://paleoamerican.fr/web/app.php/`.
This is the tree in the host !

- / folder
  http://hpics.li/c7cfee6

-This is public_html folder that I create to put all folder and file except web folder

- http://hpics.li/9899cf9

Please help Me, they will be work tomorrow.
Thanks.

Comment: I add this file **.htaccess** to public_html. i download if from github [https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/master/web/.htaccess]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: I need to Deploying my app, I shared with you what i do but that don't work !

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `www` folder then you must update accordingly the paths that are in `app.php`. In this case

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
// ....
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
```

becomes

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
// ....
require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/app/AppKernel.php';
```

Follows the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory) in this regard.

Comment: open your `AppKernel.php` and remove `new AppBundle\AppBundle(),`

Comment: I do it they show me an other Error please make a lock.

Comment: Try to do some debugging on your own